# Owl Craousel + Animate.css - Animation dont work

Tags: javascript, html, scale, owl-carousel, animate.css

I'm using owl carousel + animate.css to achieve an effect for my carousel but the code just doesn't work for me.

I want the first card to zoom out and disappear as the second card slides in.

Here is what I have tried so far.

https://codepen.io/whoisda/pen/eYEaVGd

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 
  $("#owl-example").owlCarousel({
    navigation: true,
    navigationText: ["", ""],
    singleItem: true,
    loop: true,
    autoplay: true,
    animateIn: 'animate__fadeIn',
    animateOut: 'animate__zoomOut',
    items:4,
    margin:30,
    stagePadding:100,
    smartSpeed:400,
    slideSpeed: 300
  });
  
});
```

I'm using :
animateOut: 'animate__zoomOut',

This is the design/animation should look something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUHYY.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the plugin document:
You can not use animate with more than one item is displayed

if U use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 
  $("#owl-example").owlCarousel({
    navigation: true,
    navigationText: ["", ""],
    singleItem: true,
    loop: true,
    autoplay: true,
    animateIn: 'animate__fadeIn',
    animateOut: 'animate__zoomOut',
    items:1,
    margin:30,
    stagePadding:100,
    smartSpeed:400,
    slideSpeed: 300
  });
  
});
```

it well be fine But show just one item

Visit https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/animate.html

> Animate functions work only with one item and only in browsers that support perspective property.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: i Hope my Answer getting better 
If there is a problem, thank you for telling me

Comment: Thanks a lot. I missed the first part of that sentence it seems. The slider is working but it's not the way I would like to. But this is the correct answer.